# If $a_0 x^n + ... + a_n = 0$ has more than n distinct roots, each coefficient is zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question in my textbook needs proving; I've tried doing it, but I'm stuck after a few steps.
**What I understood from my teacher:**

We could use the method of contradiction to prove this statement. If it has n+1 roots, then zero - the polynomial on the R.H.S.- will have n+1 factors.

Let's say that $\alpha_0, \alpha_1 ... \alpha_n $ are the roots, then :-

$a_0 (x-\alpha_0)(x-\alpha_1) ... (x-\alpha_n)$ will be the n+1 factors.

what do I do next? I can't figure out how we could go forward to reach the conclusion that each coefficient is zero.

Comment: What is the degree of that polynomial?

Comment: If at least one coefficient is not $0$, we have a polynomial with degree from $0$ to $n$ having at most $n$ roots (I assume you deal with the real or the complex numbers). This is a contradiction to the assumption that there are MORE THAN $n$ roots.

Answer (score 1):

Use the factor theorem, if it has $n+1$ roots then it is of the form $(x-\alpha_{1})\times…\times (x-\alpha_{n+1})\times p(x)$, now prove that $p(x)$ must be the zero polynomial, otherwise the degree of the polynomial will be greater than $n$.Hence all coefficients are zero.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let us assume the case of a quadratic polynomial with roots $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$
$$p(x) = a(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$$
As $p(x)$ is a second degree polynomial, it can have a maximum of 2 roots. Let us assume that a third root $\beta$ also exists. Substituting the same, we get
$$p(\beta) = a(\beta-\alpha_1)(\beta-\alpha_2) = 0$$
As $\beta$ is another unique root, $\beta\ne\alpha_1$ and $\beta\ne\alpha_2$. The only way to to still satisfy the equation is to have $a=0$. However, note that this turns $p(x)$ into the zero polynomial. This argument can be easily extended to all higher degree polynomials. Hence an n-degree polynomial can only have up to n roots.